# Jade (node.js) - more than one class on an element?

Tags: pug

in jade one can write:

```
div.container
```

and it compiles into:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

But what if you have several classes like:

```
<div class="span 4"><div>
```

I have written it like this:

```
div(class="span 4")
```

But I am thinking: Is there not a better way of doing it in jade?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-2):

> how about some classes?
>
> ```
> div.user-details
> ```
>
> renders `<div class="user-details"></div>`
>
> multiple classes? and an id? sure:
>
> ```
> div#foo.bar.baz
> ```
>
> renders `<div id="foo" class="bar baz"></div>`

Comment: This does not work for me (2.0.4 version of pug). It first adds the classes and at the end it appends the id.  div#foo.bar.baz will generate <div class="bar baz" id="foo"></div>.

Comment: @ovidiu-miu looks like that worked just fine to me. The order of attributes doesn’t matter, so it’s all the same.

Comment: You are correct. I was misled by the applied order of css.

Answer (score 9):

The following format

```
    div#MyBox.span12.blueButton.moveLeft
```

will create

```
    <div id="MyBox" class="span12 blueButton moveLeft"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to specify `div`

```
#MyBox.span12.blueButton.moveLeft
```

will apply the selected class and id on a `div` element :

> Since div's are such a common choice of tag, it is the default if you
>   omit the tag name:
>   `.content` compiles to `<div class="content"></div>`

See the Pug (new name for Jade) [documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html).

However you have to specify the tags of each and every other element you use
with an id or class.

Ex.

```
body
  #page
    header.row
      h1= title
    .row
      p Express App
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can combine the `.classname` syntax with the `class` attribute:

```
// Input:
.foo.bar(class="baz qux")

// Output:
<div class="foo bar baz qux"></div>
```

And the `class` attribute also supports arrays and objects for more advanced use cases.

From the [*Class Attributes* section in the documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#class-attributes) (slightly modified for clarity):

> The `class` attribute can be a string,
> like any normal attribute;
> but it can also be an array of class names,
> which is handy when generated from JavaScript.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> - const classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>
> a(class=classes)
>
> //- the class attribute may also be repeated to merge arrays
> a.bang(class=classes class=['bing'])
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```html
> <a class="foo bar baz"></a>
> <a class="bang foo bar baz bing"></a>
> ```
>
> It can also be an object which maps class names to `true` or `false` values.
> This is useful for applying conditional classes.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> - const currentUrl = '/about'
>
> a(class={active: currentUrl === '/'} href='/') Home
> a(class={active: currentUrl === '/about'} href='/about') About
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```html
> <a href="/">Home</a>
> <a class="active" href="/about">About</a>
> ```